# Precision of DataGridView doubles when copying to clipboard

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am displaying an array of doubles using a DataGridView.
(There is no limitation on the dimensions of the array)

I intentionally don't display every decimal place of each double to the user, instead I set the format of the cell to something like:

```
dataGridView.Columns[i].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "f3";
```

So, a value 1.112233 would be displayed as "1.112".

However, when copying a selected cell to the clipboard and pasting into Excel I only ever get the displayed precision. I would like to know if there is a straightforward way to specify that I want the cell **Value** to be copied to the clipboard not the **FormattedValue**?

Please note that I am not limited to copying single cells, I would like the user to be able to copy multiple cells, ie

```
dataGridView.MultiSelect = true;
dataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect;
```

When debugging I have verified that the **Value** property on the cell does indeed contain the original double.

I have specified the the **ValueType** is a double.

I attempted to override the  `Ctrl + C` command with a key down event and output the selected cells to the clipboard manually. However, the order of the cells in the `dataGridView.SelectedCells` does not necessarily match the order in which they were selected. For example, when two neighbouring cells are selected their order seems to have been arbitrarily reversed. ie select a value in column 0 and then a value in column 1, the order in the `dataGridView.SelectedCells` was column 1 and then column 0.

It feels too convoluted and excessively inefficient to have to manually sort these back into a sensible order before then manually copying to the clipboard.

Is there a simple way to do this or do I just have to put the effort into the manual copy?

Comment: I am confident it will be easier to do this manually. Using the OS “Copy/Paste” for this has numerous drawbacks. The problem you will have with the individual “CellSelect” selection mode is that the “copy” is not going to respect the “column” order. The “SelectedCells” collection is a collection of “cells” not rows. Therefore, the code will need to maintain the row/column order when pasting the cells.

Comment: As you have also noted the “selected” cells are in the reverse order by which the user “selected” each cell. This is the grids default behavior and the same would be true for any “Selection” mode. Therefore, if order is important, then you will need to “sort” the selected cells somehow.

Comment: Lastly, even if the grid is set with a “FullRowSelect” selection mode and the “selected” rows were sorted, one other problem arises using the OS copy/paste… the “copy” command will “IGNORE” “empty” selected cells. This is going to mess up the column order for those rows that have an empty cell. IMHO using the OS copy/paste is not necessarily the best approach.